# What's the meaning of 'give cleavage'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I know both the meaning of *give* and *cleavage*, but I cannot understand some sentences including those. This is from an [article about pregnancy](http://flicmeds.org/cg/2309_pregnant_belly_first_trimester/ltt1.html).

> Loving your new dewy, pregnant glow? Thank the hormones HCG and progesterone (they increase the number of oil glands in your face, making your complexion shinier and smoother) and your boosted blood volume, which can make your skin slightly flushed and plump. **And if the girls are giving you all kinds of nice cleavage** these days, it's because estrogen and progesterone are spurring milk-producing glands to grow there (and there's plenty more of that to come)!

Comment: "the girls" in this sentence means *your breasts*, and "all kinds of cleavage" means *dramatic breast size*; so overall the clause means "if you suddenly have bigger breasts".

Answer (score 4):

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20girls)

> **the girls**
> Affectionate term for a woman's breasts.

When a woman has large breasts, the cleavage between the breasts becomes much more noticeable and attractive. The quote is saying that you'll notice this improvement when you become pregnant, because of the hormones that promote breast growth.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, it's not "if you suddenly have bigger breasts", it's "if you see that girls these days have big and nice breasts" it's because... .

Comment: That is only true if you assume that the sentence is directed at male readers. I think it much more likely to be addressing pregnant women.

Comment: And why female readers can't mention that other women's breasts bigger these days?

Comment: How does your pregnancy make other womens' breasts get bigger?

Comment: @Hellion I didn't understand that girls=breasts here. I thought of literary meaning.