# What's the meaning of 'make sense' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

It means to understand and to be reasonable, but I don't know how to translate it in the writing below. It sounds like 'Remember' but I am not sure. Please help me!
* And does 'top' here means 'T-shirt'?

> As your uterus continues to expand upward -- the top is nearly midway between your breasts and belly button now -- your middle will grow longer and wider. 
>   ***Makes sense***; your baby's going to be pushing past the two-pound mark in no time at all, and you've gotta make room for her in there

Comment: "Makes sense" means exactly what you said it means. It is understandable and reasonable that your middle will grow grow because the baby is growing inside you. It is logical. "The top" is understood to be "the top of the uterus".

Comment: Note that I did not post as an answer because I would like to help out the OP, but this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: They've simply omitted the subject: it's short for "That makes sense" mean "That is understandable".

Comment: It is an odd use of the words.  It could be much better written.

Comment: And no, *top* is the top of the uterus not “a top” like a t-shirt.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, *that makes sense* means *that is understandable*. It is a well-used idiom. But I can well understand why a non-native speaker might find it difficult to make the connection.

Comment: @HotLicks This text seems to be written in an informal, conversational style. That construction is very common in conversation.

Comment: I have a feeling it's from the same source as http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370090/whats-the-meaning-of-give-cleavage/370241#370241 (the same OP, and they both seem to be targeted towards young girls learning about pregnancy). That one uses the extremely informal idiom "the girls" to refer to the breasts.

Comment: @Barmar - But in spoken language inflection helps "explain" the words.  If this text is meant to be read rather than spoken it should be reworded.

Comment: @HotLicks As a native speaker I had no trouble understanding it. I don't think inflection is particularly important for this phrase. As I read it, I simply heard it in my mind and interpreted it as if I'd heard it from a speaker.

Comment: Please edit your question title to include  *make**s** sense*

Answer (score 1):

"Makes sense" is simply an elided version of "It makes sense" -- "It" is the subject, "makes" the verb, "sense" the object of the verb.

The meaning is that the growth of the baby ("it") creates the situation ("makes") where it's sensible to expect ("sense") the uterus to likewise grow upward.

"It", in this case, is a *forward* reference to the statement about the growth of the baby, and thus the idiom "Makes sense", as used above, is *anticipating* an explanation of *why* things make sense -- it's saying "As I'm about to explain".  (Though understand that "Makes sense" might instead be used as a summary, following some statement, to assert that what was just stated was sensible.)

Answer (score 0):

Top in this sentence means 'the top of the uterus'.

Makes sense is short for 'It is reasonable for the uterus to expand and your middle to grow as I have described.'